# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' while loading with pickle

Tags: python, runtime-error, loading, pickle

I'm using Python 3.6 and Spyder (Anaconda).
I have tried many things but nothing worked out.
I don't know why this error is coming always to me while loading with pickle.

```
filename = "allfeatures.txt"
allfeatures = open(filename, 'r').read()
with open(filename) as f:
     allfeatures = list(f)
allconcat = np.vstack(list(allfeatures.values()))
```

```
TypeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
 AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Comment: You don't need pickle to load a txt file, you can just open and then read it directly.

Comment: Please put your error as a text, not as an image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pickle: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39146039/pickle-typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str)

Comment: AttributeError: '_io.BufferedReader' object has no attribute 'decode'

Answer (score 1):

You need to open your file as a binary file:

```
pickle.loads(open("accounts.txt", 'rb').read())
```

Otherwise, it's using an `str` to read the data.

Comment: then I got this error again...........UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)